# SQL*Plus save current COLUMN settings

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

In SQL*Plus, is there a way to save current [COLUMN](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve013.htm) settings similar to [STORE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve046.htm) which saves SET commands in a script?

COLUMN can be used to list the settings, but they are not in script format.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit `$ORACLE_HOME/sqlplus/admin/glogin.sql` file and add inside your col format settings :)

```
[ora11g@botor ~]$ cat /u01/app/ora11g/product/11.2.0/db_1/sqlplus/admin/glogin.sql
define _editor=vi
set lines 450
set pages 100
set time on
set timi on
set serveroutput on
......
```

Comment: Yeah, i'm using login.sql for that. However, i am looking for the *current* COLUMN settings, which may be changed for an ad hoc report.

Answer (score 1):

You can spool the output from running the 'column' command to a file. This will give you the basis of a script but you will need to ensure that each column stsement is on a single line,
e.g.

```
       COLUMN   value_col_plus_show_param ON
       HEADING  'VALUE'
       FORMAT   a30
```

Becomes

```
       COLUMN   value_col_plus_show_param ON HEADING  'VALUE' FORMAT   a30
```

You could either automate the removing of the carriage returns using sed or do it manually with your preferred editor.